# SQL Stored Procedure Throwing Error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to run the follow in CREATE a stored procedure in mySQL, but getting errors:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'AS BEGIN DECLARE col_name VARCHAR(255)' at line 2"

Here's the Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getColumnUniqueValuePercentage 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE col_name VARCHAR(255);

DECLARE col_names CURSOR FOR
  SELECT column_name
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'full_db3'
  ORDER BY ordinal_position;

SET @query = '';
SET @n := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo);

OPEN col_names;
SET @i = 0;
the_loop: LOOP

   IF @i > @num_rows THEN
        CLOSE col_names;
        LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;

    FETCH FROM col_names INTO col_name;     
        SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT ', col_name, ', COUNT(*)*100/', @n, ' as count from full_db3 group by ', col_name,' order by count desc');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
        EXECUTE stmt;
    SET @i = @i + 1;  
END LOOP the_loop;
END
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's either mysql or sql-server; not both.

Comment: Good point...got a little quick selecting from recommended tags.

Comment: Not your main issue, but `@num_rows` is never set; unless you are depending on something outside the procedure setting it, that will be a problem. I am guessing you mean `@n` and it to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is not correct. Try:

```sql
DELIMITER //

-- CREATE PROCEDURE getColumnUniqueValuePercentage
CREATE PROCEDURE getColumnUniqueValuePercentage()
-- AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE col_name VARCHAR(255);

  DECLARE col_names CURSOR FOR
    SELECT column_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = 'full_db3'
    ORDER BY ordinal_position;

  SET @query = '';
  SET @n := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo);

  OPEN col_names;
  SET @i = 0;
  the_loop: LOOP

     IF @i > @num_rows THEN
          CLOSE col_names;
          LEAVE the_loop;
      END IF;

      FETCH FROM col_names INTO col_name;     
          SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT ', col_name, ', COUNT(*)*100/', @n, ' as count from full_db3 group by ', col_name,' order by count desc');
          PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
          EXECUTE stmt;
      SET @i = @i + 1;  
  END LOOP the_loop;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

**UPDATE**

```sql
-- CREATE PROCEDURE getColumnUniqueValuePercentage
CREATE PROCEDURE `getColumnUniqueValuePercentage`()
-- AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE `done` BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
    -- DECLARE `col_name` VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE `col_name` VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE `n` INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;    
    DECLARE `col_names` CURSOR FOR
        SELECT `column_name`
        FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
        WHERE `table_name` = 'full_db3'
        ORDER BY `ordinal_position`;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET `done` := TRUE;

    -- SET @query = '';

    SET `n` := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `foo`);
    OPEN `col_names`;

    -- SET @i = 0;

    `the_loop`: LOOP
        FETCH FROM `col_names` INTO `col_name`;

        -- IF @i > @num_rows THEN
        IF `done` THEN
            CLOSE `col_names`;
            LEAVE `the_loop`;
        END IF;

        -- FETCH FROM col_names INTO col_name;

        SET @`query` := CONCAT('SELECT ', `col_name`, ', COUNT(*) * 100 / ', `n`, ' `COUNT`
                                FROM `full_db3`
                                GROUP BY ', `col_name`,
                                ' ORDER BY `COUNT` DESC');
        PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`query`;
        EXECUTE `stmt`;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
        -- SET @i = @i + 1;  
    END LOOP `the_loop`;
END//
```

Comment: @jonmrich: Recommendation, use [13.6.4.1. Local Variable Syntax DECLARE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-local-variable.html), if applicable, instead [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html).

Comment: Like this? `DECLARE @col_name VARCHAR(255);`

Comment: Pretty sure he meant `DECLARE n INT` and `DECLARE i INT`; I'd say `DECLARE query VARCHAR(xxx)`, but you couldn't prepare from that. In those cases, I try to use much more uniquely named user vars (such as  [procname]_query or even a random GUID as a prefix for all of a particular proc's user vars)

Comment: @jonmrich: One option is shown on updating the answer. Adjust as necessary.

Comment: @Uueerdo: One option is shown on updating the answer.